# Scammed by Boiler Room & Now Fake German Law Firm

Tags: stocks, investing, scams, fraud, law

Late last year I invested heavily in what is now apparently a "Boiler Room". After trying to find any way to get my money back I came across a law firm. I found nothing about the lawyer handling my case apart from repeating web images and profiles.

They said that they could resolve a scam in an overseas wealth management company but is was just another attempt at additional financial extortion.  The company changed its name and they asked for additional fees. They used the same tactics as the original fraudsters and then ignored all of my calls and emails.

After doing more research, I found that the company had posted fake reviews from their Google account (each review had only one review). Everything was red flags. After calling local authorities,  I found out that they are not registered in any of the German  legal bars to which they claim membership. This made me visit their branches which only hosted other small companies.  None knew of their existence!

After many phone calls and emails I had no luck. I was contacted by email a short while after by another firm saying that they are still looking into the case and need 8,500 EUR to continue. This is strange since I have never dealt with this company. I  asking a friend about this and he found that the same website was hosted on the same server with the same old WordPress template.

Can anyone suggest how I can reclaim my funds in this law firm as they are closer to home? Has anyone dealt with a fraudulent law firm? Any feedback will be kindly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: The money you've given away already is unfortunately gone.  It's highly unlikely you'll ever identify the culprits, let alone get it back.  It's pretty clear these lawyers are *also scamming you* and depending on how you originally "found" them, they may, in fact, be the same scammers as before, pretending to "help" you get "them."   Stop throwing good money after bad.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the police?

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone suggest how I can reclaim my funds in this Law firm as they are closer to home.

That is an assumption you are making. They could be anywhere, as scammers have your details, they could have directed to fake law firm that seems near you...

Practically the money is gone and may never come back...

You can register a complaint with local law enforcement.